# Tamper Monkey Image Replace

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I need to replace multiple images with the use of a tampermonkey script. This is what I have

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name         My Fancy New Userscript
    // @namespace    http://your.homepage/
    // @version      0.1
    // @description  enter something useful
    // @author       You
    // @match        http://*/*
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    var images = document.getElementsByTagName ("img"); 
    var x=0; 
    while(x<images.length) 
    { 
    if(images[x].src == "http://images.immortalday.com/images/items/238.png") 
    { 
    images[x].src = "http://kindersay.com/files/images/hamburger.png"; 
    } 
    x=x+1;    
    }
```

And this works great for a single image replacement! How would I be able to add more to the code so that I can replace multiple images instead of just one?

Comment: FYI this is on Chrome not sure if this matters :p

Comment: How do you decide which images to replace? And what with?

Comment: The first one is the image it looks for and the second one is the image it replaces.